# Why did QGIS 3.6 crash?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, layers

I have clipped a raster file using a shapefile as a mask. [image]

And I tried to export the new layer and modified the projection from WGS 84 EPSG:4326 to EPSG: 102022 Africa Albers Equal Area Conic. [image]
When export was processing QGIS suddenly crashed. [image]
What went wrong?